# Get-ChildItem with filter returns files that match but includes some that dont

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "my-path" -Filter "ABGH14__*"
```

When I run this I get several files that start with the string "ABGH14__" but also a few that obviously DO NOT start with that string in their file name.
What can I check?

If I change to use Where-Object 
I get list with no extraneous names included.
Why not the first example?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "my-path" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'ABGH14__*}
```

Comment: Is the path a file system path?

Comment: please show a few of the wrong file names.

Comment: Could it be you are also looking at directories with names starting with `ABGH14__`? If you want to limit the result to files only, add the `-File` switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, -filter can match the short file name versions.

```
cmd /c dir /x my-path\ABGH14__*  # show short filenames

get-childitem -filter *~1*  # would match a lot of short filenames
```